# I created a table and I'm trying to modify it but I get this error

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I started tody with Python SQL Database conexion (or in general python databse collection i guess)
and I was following a tutorial on youtube about how to create and modify the table, but at the moment when I tried to modify it this happens.

I am not sure because I was reading here some solutions and sometimes there is a problem with the reference (I guess table name) or if you created the table out of the public or something like that.

I attach a picture to have a better reference, thank you if you help me

[image]

I tried searching on PostgreSQL documentation, rewatching the video and searching here on stackoverflow but there's some sort of thing that I still don't know about working with PostgreSQL so I didn't triet

Comment: Why don’t you post the error message in plain text in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems with your statement. 1: Your table name contains upper case letters. This indicates it was created with the name in double quotes("..."). Double quoting makes the name case sensitive and requires that you **always** use them when referencing the table. 2: You also incorrectly used double quotes in the `values` clause. In this case double quoting indicates the name of an object (here a column). Literal values take single quotes. Try

```
insert into "PersonaPrueba"(Nonbre,Apellido) 
  values ('Susana','Maricia');
```

The double quote requirement will also apply to column names if they were also created with double quotes.